# How do I formate spaces in terminal for FFMPEG metadata

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, terminal

I can't get FFMPEG to accept any spaces when I try to assign it to the metadata. Below is the command I am using in Terminal on MacOS. It gives me an error: `[NULL @ 0x7fce76026600] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'World' World: Invalid argument`

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner \
-i Trolls.World.Tour.2020.Bluray-2160p.m2ts \
-ss 00:10:00 -t 00:1:00 \
-pix_fmt yuv420p10le \
-map_chapters 0 \
-metadata:s:t:0 filename="" -metadata:s:t:0 mimetype="image/jpeg" \
-metadata title=“Trolls World Tour” \
-map 0:0 -metadata:s:v:0 language=eng -metadata:s:v:0 title=“Trolls World Tour” \
-map 0:2 -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:0 title=“Dolby TrueHD 7.1 Atmos” \
-map 0:6 -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 title=“AC-3 2.0” \
-c:v libx265 -preset slow -crf 16 \
-x265-params keyint=60:bframes=3:vbv-bufsize=75000:vbv-maxrate=75000:hdr-opt=1:repeat-headers=1:colorprim=bt2020:transfer=smpte2084:colormatrix=bt2020nc:master-display="G(13250,34500)B(7500,3000)R(34000,16000)WP(15635,16450)L(10000000,500)" \
-c:a copy \
Trolls.World.Tour.2020.2160p.BluRay.REMUX.HEVC.TrueHD.7.1.Atmos.mkv
```

I have tried `'title="Trolls World Tour"'` `title=Trolls" "World" "Tour` to no luck.

Using `title="Trolls\ World\ Tour"` works but then the title includes the backslashes.

Any thoughts?

Comment: try single quote   title='troolls world.. '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the “smart / fancy” quotes with "normal double quotes".

- Bad: `“` & `”`
- Good: `"`

Comment: Wow, that was problem. I was typing it up in a rich text file and it had the fancy quotes. Kudos!